# Can't install codec nor upgrade pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am working on a project that has many encode and decode issues,so I tried to install codec module for my python 3.7:

so I did:

```
$pip install codec
```

and the Command prompt windows showed as below:

> Collecting codec   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement codec (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for
>   codec You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is
>   available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip
>   install --upgrade pip' command.

then I did the pip upgrade followed as the above to version 18.1:

```
$python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and  the Command windows showed as below:

> Installing collected packages: pip   Found existing installation: pip
>   10.0.1
>       Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
>         Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1 Successfully installed pip-18.1

and I used

```
$pip list
```

to check the pip version is 18.1>>>It did upgrade.
then I did install codecs again:

```
$pip install codec
```

and  the Command windows showed as below:

> Collecting codec   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement codec (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for
>   codec

so I put another command :

```
$pip install --upgrade pip -vvv
```

and  the Command windows showed as below:

> Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
>   Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be
>   incorrect
>
> --------leave out between section----------------------------------------
>
> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
>   c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (18.1)

What should I do next?
Is anyone could help me,please.

Comment: Did you happen to install `tensorflow` recently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[codec](https://pypi.org/project/codec/) doesn't provide any installation packages — no wheels, no eggs, no source distributions.

Its [git repository](https://github.com/metagriffin/codec) doesn't contain any code beyond `setup.py`.

I'm sure the package is not what you want. You're probably looking for [module `codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html). It is in the standard repository, that is it's always available, no need to install it.

Comment: Thank you so much ,Just like your mention "codecs" no need to install it .Appreciate your help..